# Individual buttons for each row cell, created as device found

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I'm trying to make a custom cell, witch the prototypes cells are generated as it found the devices, that means one row for each device. Each button has to act on its own device. the custom cell: [image]

I've created a UITableViewCell and declared the label, button and image. I'm having trouble to make the button act as individual buttons at TableViewController.Here is the TableViewController.m

```
- (interruptorTableCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"dimmableCell";
interruptorTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
BinaryLight1Device *dispositivoApresentadoNaTabRetiradoDaListaDeFiltrados = [self.model.devicesFiltrados objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.accessoryView = cell.ligaDeslBtnPro;
cell.ligaDeslBtnPro.tag = indexPath.row;
[cell.ligaDeslBtnPro addTarget:self action:@selector(ligaDeslBtn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
cell.dimmableLabel.text  = [dispositivoApresentadoNaTabRetiradoDaListaDeFiltrados friendlyName];
return cell;
}
```

Here is the button action,declared in TableView Cell:

```
- (IBAction)ligaDeslBtn:(UIButton *)sender
{
interruptorTableCell *cell = (interruptorTableCell*)[sender superview];
NSIndexPath *index=[menuView indexPathForCell:cell];
BinaryLight1Device *deviceBinaryLight = [model.devicesFiltrados objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
NSMutableString *statusDispositivos = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
if (sender)
{
    if ([statusDispositivos isEqualToString:@"0"])
    {
     [[deviceBinaryLight switchPower]SetarValorLigadoDesligado:@"1"];
     [[deviceBinaryLight switchPower]RetornarValorLigadoDesligado:statusDispositivos];
    }
    else if ([statusDispositivos isEqualToString:@"1"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Desligando dispositivo");
        [[deviceBinaryLight switchPower]SetarValorLigadoDesligado:@"0"];
        [[deviceBinaryLight switchPower]RetornarValorLigadoDesligado:statusDispositivos];
     }
}
```

I think my problem is with OO, I'm declaring it correct? where should I do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A approach I tried once and worked for me was add a button for each cell and work with tag:

Add this to

```
- (interruptorTableCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{}


// Configure your buttons according your needs
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(530.0f, 20.0f, 87.0f, 34.0f);
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(ligaDeslBtn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell addSubview:button];
    button.tag = indexPath.row;
```

And the, on your button event, add on the beginning:
//Identifies wich button was tapped.

```
NSInteger row = [sender tag];
```