# Unable to access tableview property to get the index of button clicked in custom cell

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

i have created a custom table cell app . each cell contains buttons. i found on stackoverflow that the best way to find out whether button in row 1 was clicked or row 2 was clicked was to use this method

```
CGPoint hitPoint = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView]; 
NSIndexPath *hitIndex = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:hitPoint];
```

however i cannot use this because i am not getting an error at self.tableView.

this is because instead of using a UItableviewcontroller i am using UIViewcontroller  and implementing the tableviewdelegate and tableviewdatasource. and the viewcontroller does not have any property tableview.

i cannot change the UIViewcontroller to UItableViewcontroller because everywhere in the code i am pushing the viewcontrollers using fileowner

So how can i get rid of the self.tableview error

Comment: what is your table name? is that your tablename is default?

Comment: ve you created property for your tableView

Comment: @interface SerAgTableViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {

Comment: nope am asking tableview IBoutlet name

Comment: I answered something similar. check it out. Maybe it can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19519602/individual-buttons-for-each-row-cell-created-as-device-found/19519955#19519955

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to keep the indexPath.row value in the custom cell object right when you create it.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   //Your cell creation logic here. 

    //Set indexpath in the custom cell. 
    cell.parentIndexPath = indexPath; 

    return cell;
}
```

and when the button is clicked, you can check it inside the custom cell object:

```
-(IBAction) buttonClicked: (id) sender {
  NSLog(@"User clicked on index path %@", self.parentIndexPath);

}
```

You have to declare the parentIndexPath in the custom cell header (.h) file.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *parentIndexPath;
```

Comment: You need to be careful with this approach that you keep the index path updated - for example when inserting and deleting rows.

Comment: Yes, you need to refresh in that case.

Comment: it give me an error - property of type parentIndexPath not found on object of type POtablecell

Comment: You need to add that property in the custom cell.

Answer (score 1):

try to create property for your table

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;
```

then set myTableView instead of self.tableview. i tried this and this one works for me well

```
 CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:myTableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [buddyListTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];

    NSLog(@"Index Path  :%d",indexPath.row);
```

Comment: did exactly this . got rid of the error. but index path on clicking both row1 button and row 2 button was 0 . any idea why. i am creating the button programmatically by the way . could it be the reason

Comment: bro wait what you ding you printing  NSLog(@"Index Path  :%@",self.parentIndexPath);

Comment: but you ve to print NSIndexPath *indexPath this NSLog(@"Index Path :%@",indexPath);

Comment: no that was after i tried your method i started trying the srijeeth method on this page . its a mistake but i actually used your NSLOG

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45925/discussion-between-yohan-and-silverkid)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
CGPoint hitPoint = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:(UITableView *)self.view];
```

But you should have an `@property` which points to the table view really.